# Display an alert in Android while screen is locked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am looking for a way to show the user a message on an Android device even when the screen is locked. What I've found is that most of the popup examples, such as SMS popups, appear only once - but won't display again the second time the user presses the power-button to turn the screen on (but leaves it locked).

I'd love any advice the community can provide on how to display a persistent message on the lock-screen.

Answer (score -3):

Tyr to use LayoutInflater and PopUpWindow class for this purpose

Comment: because you didn't think about your answer